# nodejs : sessionID is changing after redirect. How to keep user session data persistent?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, cookies, express-session

have seen many similar issues but can't figure out how to fix it.
I have an express server, using cookies sessions. The server is calling the google auth api.

Because it is a app for multi users, I have to associate the google auth information to the user ssession

I'm saving these auth data in the session after getting them back from google.
The data are well saved in the session. No issue here

But after redirecting to another express route, the session is different and therefore, can't access the saved data.

Here is the code

Thks

```
app.use(
  session({
    name: SESSION_NAME,
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: parseInt(SESSION_LIFETIME, 10), // 24H in config file
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: true,
      secure: !IN_DEV
    }
  })
);

googleRouter.get("/oauthcallback", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.query.code && req.query.code !== "") {
      const oauth2Client = initGoogleAuth();
      const tokens = await getGoogleToken(oauth2Client, req.query.code);

      if (tokens && tokens !== "") {
        const s = await saveTokensInSession(req.session, tokens);

        oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

        // save data in session
        req.session.oauth2Client = oauth2Client;
        req.session.save();

        // oauth2Client is well saved here in session
        console.log(req.session.oauth2Client);

        //redirect to the next url

        res.redirect("/googleauth/test");


      } else res.send("error while getting tokens");
    } else res.send("error while getting  authorization code");
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(`error while getting token : ${error}`);
  }
});


googleRouter.get("/test", async (req, res) => {

 // oauth2Client is empty  here and sessionID is different
 console.log(req.session.oauth2Client);
});
```

Comment: seems no answer

Comment: Have you tried if redirecting manually (like at the browser) the session data still available?

Comment: sorry I didn't get your point. What do you mean by "redirecting manually" ?

Comment: Yeah like, instead of redirecting with `res.redirec("/googleauth/test")`, comment that line and put a `res.end()`, then at your browser type the url and check if the session data is available that way

Answer (score 1):

I have same your problem, I've tried with sameSite is "lax", it's work fine.

```
app.use(
  session({
    name: SESSION_NAME,
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: parseInt(SESSION_LIFETIME, 10), // 24H in config file
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "lax",
      secure: !IN_DEV
    }
  })
);
```

But I think sameSite equal "strict" is necessary for security better
Everyone have any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**npm install --save cors**

allow access to the appropriate port access through the cors middleware

```
app.use (cors ({
         credentials: true,
         origin: [
                 "http: // your domain address",
                 "http: // yourdomain address: port"
                 ]
}));
```

Try to redirect through the callback of the "save" function.

```
req.session.save ((err) => {
// try to redirect within callback function
res.redirect ("/googleauth/test");
})
```

In case of post method, replace it as follows.

```
res.redirect (307, "/googleauth/test");
```

Then set withCredentials: true in the config of your data transfer module (ex: axios, etc.) in your client code.

```
const config = {
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      withCredentials:true
      };

axios.post('http://your domain address:port/route',{},config)
   .then( response => {
   //response.data your codes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue running locally where on res.redirect, the session ID changed and I was not able to retrieve the saved session data. I spent many hours looking into this issue, tried all the answers above including explicitly running `req.session.save()`. What fixed it for me was that I realized I was
redirecting to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/path` while my original page was on `http://localhost:3000/path`.

Express apparently treats those as separate domains and therefore I was getting a new session ID on redirect even though they appeared to lead to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a while back. I resolved it by only proceeding once I got the callback back from the save method. Looks silly but got it working for me alright.

```
req.session.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.send("err while saving session information");
    }
    console.log(req.session.oauth2Client);
    return res.redirect("/googleauth/test");
});
```

or

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    req.session.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
        resolve(res.redirect("/googleauth/test"));
    });
});
```

Let me know if it does the job for you.
Reference: https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/660